# A value of type 'List<Customer>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<Customer>>'

Tags: flutter

How to convert  'List' to 'Future<List>'. I need get two type ('List' & 'Future<List>' ) in different places

My api response

```
var data = jsonDecode(r.body);
  custList.add(new Customer(
      data[i]['CustomerID'],
      '${data[i]['ProfileImageUrl']}' + '${data[i]['ProfileImage']}',
      '${data[i]['CompanyName']}',
      data[i]['Email'],
      data[i]['RegisterNumber'],
      data[i]['PhoneNumber'],
      data[i]['BillingStreet'],
      data[i]['BillingCity'],
      data[i]['BillingZip'],
      data[i]['MasterCountryName'],
      data[i]['MasterStateName'],
      data[i]['Type'],
      new customeraddress(data[i]['BillingStreet'],
          data[i]['BillingCity'], data[i]['BillingZip']),
    status,
      data[i]['CustomerTaxExemptType'],
    data[i]['MasterCountryID'],
    data[i]['MasterStateID'],
  ));
```

Comment: show where you defined your List<customer>

Comment: In Customers class 

class Customers {
  List<Customer> custList;

Comment: Create a method that returns `Future<List<Customers>>` and then convert it to `List<Customers>` using `await`.
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: is it possible to convert List<Customers> to Future<List<Customers>>.

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert 'List' to 'Future<List>'.

If you are not entirely sure if you get a `T` or a `Future<T>`, you can use the `FutureOr<T>` ([documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html)) class.

To create a `Future<T>` from a value to satisfy some compiler syntax, you can use the named constructor `Future.value` ([documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.value.html)).

For more information on Futures: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)